# Kestrel command throws Unable to load libuv. Make sure libuv is installed and available as libuv.so.1

Tags: mono, centos, asp.net-core, libuv, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to run the samples from https://github.com/aspnet/home

I followed all the steps from the [documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html#installing-on-debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives) but I can't make it work.

I'm running `dnx . kestrel` (on CentOS), the error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load libuv. Make sure libuv is installed and available as libuv.so.1
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.Load (System.String dllToLoad) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelEngine..ctor (ILibraryManager libraryManager, IApplicationShutdown appShutdownService) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Kestrel.ServerFactory.Start (IServerInformation serverInformation, System.Func`2 application) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have `libuv.so.1.0.0` in `/usr/local/lib`

```
[/usr/local/lib]$ ls
libuv.a  libuv.la  libuv.so  libuv.so.1  libuv.so.1.0.0  pkgconfig
```

And I also added symbolic links for `libuv.so.1` in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`

I even checked [kestrel's source code](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/KestrelEngine.cs) but I couldn't find what's the problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the library loader path to include your local lib dir and the LoadLibrary in [Libuv.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/47d7f73bdce175e6a47acbd96c6ec04b91c078b4/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/Networking/Libuv.cs) should find it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
dnx . kestrel
```

`man dlopen` for more details:

```
Linux Shared Library Search Path
From the dlopen(3) man page, the necessary shared libraries needed by the program are searched for in the following order:

1) A colon-separated list of directories in the user’s LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
2)....
```